# asp.net reportviewer displaymode as printpreview

Tags: asp.net, report

I use webforms.reportviewer. 
I have already read many blog and article about report pagination and interactive page size.
My purpose is a similar to winforms.reportviewer's printlayout display mode. 
But I did not find any solution about it. 
I checked telerik's reportviewer control, and they can solve this issue.
But I couldn't figure out how...

Somebody any idea? Unfortunately I could't figure out, how it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering your report as a PDF to the screen should give you what you want.

It will show your users what will get printed. There is not interactivity with this report.

You can do this using [Url access parameters and rs commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)

Format is like:

```
http://ReportServer/<Report_Name>&rs:Format=PDF
```

Comment: I realized maybe I miss something. I use reportviewer to show rdlc reports.